# Why is my multiple condition Regular Expression slow in C# .NET

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regular expressions and I'm trying to match the following:

```
(Word1 or Word2 or Word3 or Word4 or Word5 and doesn't contain Word6)
or
(Word7 and Word1)
or
(Word8 and Word9)
```

I've tried several different ways and this is the only one which works as I need it to. However, it is very slow against high volumes of test (1 page of A4)

```
(?=.*(WORD1|WORD2|WORD3|WORD4|WORD5))^(?!.*WORD6)|(?=.*(WORD7))(?=.*(WORD1))|(?=.*(WORD8))(?=.*(WORD9))
```

Is there a way I can simplify this to make it quicker?

Note**
I'm even more confused - when using the pattern in an online regex site (www.myregextester.com) it works in milliseconds, however in .Net C# using :

```
if (Regex.Match(docText, pattern,RegexOptions.Compiled).Success)
{
}
```

it takes over 25 seconds.

Comment: Both of your tags are in the title. You know that the tags are used for search engines so it's redundant to add them also to the title? Instead provide a title that makes it easy to find your question, if someone has a similar problem in future.

Comment: First of all, group your `WORD` into one `(WORD)` clause...

Comment: Hi BadMiscuit - how do you mean?

Comment: Why do you have to use a regex? Why not use `.Contains`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2010/08/03/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-ii-taking-charge-of-backtracking-ron-petrusha/

If you can eliminate much of the special parenthesis you will notice a speed improvement.

Comment: Hi, maybe im not too clear but WORD1 WORD2 etc isnt WORD1 WORD2 it could be cat mouse dog so [1-5] wont work. The negative is required because in the first condition its dog or cat but the text cant contain rabit.

Comment: Maybe you should add those details to your question

Comment: hi Calvin - if trying to match dog & cat they could be anywhere in the text and in any order. The example i gave works exactly how i need it to it's just very slow. I have just edited the question because the pattern works fast on an external website but slow on c# regex.match